# TouchesMoved with UITouch

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uitouch, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

I'm trying to create a simple application where you can move your UIImageView by touching him and dragging him around.

my UIImageView is called imv

```
-(void ) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];

if([touch view] == self.imv){
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    self.imv.center = location;

}
}

-(void ) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];

if([touch view] == self.imv){
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    self.imv.center = location;

}
}
```

i'am trying to solve this like whole day and i don't know what is wrong. If i disable if statement it's working else not. What can i do?

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you've subclassed `UIImageView` (unlikely), your view is receiving the touch events.

These days it's simpler & more usual to use a `UIGestureRecognizer` for this kind of thing, in this case a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

e.g.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragImageView:)];
[self.imv addGestureRecognizer:pan];


- (void)dragImageView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)dragImageView {
    if(UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan  == state) {
        originalCenter = self.imv.center;    // add CGPoint originalCenter; member
    } else if(UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged == state) {
        CGPoint translate = [pan translationInView:self.imv.superview];
        self.imv.center = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x + translate.x, originalCenter.y + translate.y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a bit of experimenting, it seems that the `[touch view]` is returning the main `UIView` and not your subview, hence the problem with the `if` statement not working (I added the `UIImageView` in a storyboard xib). EDIT- it's because `UIImageView`s don't handle touch events by default - see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) . When adding a regular `UIView` in the `viewDidLoad` seems to work as you would expect.

Anyway, this adapted version of your code works for me

```
-(void)moveImageForTouches:(NSSet*)touches
{
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(self.imv.frame, location))
    {
        self.imv.center = location;
    }

}

-(void ) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self moveImageForTouches:touches];
}

-(void ) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self moveImageForTouches:touches];
}
```

Comment: HI. 
I tried to used this code, but when you move UIImageView fast you lose item.